# How do I authenticate against Azure (subscription) from an external program

Tags: azure, authentication, pass-through

I am trying to develop a web application using which I want to be able to connect to my Azure subscription, read all my resources and display those back on my app. I only need the name, IP and resource type. I know I can authenticate against Azure using PowerShell but not quite sure how I achieve this using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Most Azure service REST APIs have client libraries that provide a native interface for using Azure services.

- .NET
- Java
- Node.js
- Python
- Azure CLI 2.0 SDK

We do not have a client library for PHP.  I would recommend call the Azure REST API from PHP to accomplish the task you are looking at.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/

Authentication is also discussed in the link above.